# How to convert a date to a hours and minute in a variable in python 3?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset with has the date format as follows `2021-06-18 23:30:00` which is read by python as a character.
I want to create a variable that only contains the hour and minutes of the dates.
This is what I tried with no useful results:

```
from datetime import datetime
df["hours"] = datetime.strptime(df["Date"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%H:%M')
```

The above code gives me an error.

In  R this can be done using

```
df$hours <- format(strptime(df$Date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M")
```

I also try to do the same thing on python but again it wasn't useful

```
df["hours"] = format(datetime.strptime(df["Date"],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M")
```

Both python code give me the following error:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

This my dataframe

```
df.head()

                   Date    Open    High    Low    Close Volume
0   2006-04-13 10:00:00 1921.75 1922.00 1918.00 1918.25 11782
1   2006-04-13 10:30:00 1918.25 1931.75 1918.00 1931.00 39744
2   2006-04-13 11:00:00 1931.25 1934.00 1929.00 1930.25 34385
3   2006-04-13 11:30:00 1930.50 1932.00 1928.50 1931.25 13539
4   2006-04-13 12:00:00 1931.25 1932.25 1928.25 1928.75 10045
```

Comment: What you have works with the right data: `datetime.strptime('2021-06-18 23:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%H:%M')` gives `23:30`.  Make a [mre] with a small dataframe that reproduces your issue.

Comment: It looks like `df` is a pandas dataframe with a "Date" column. If so, let us know and include an initialized _test_ dataframe in your example. It just needs a data column with a couple of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, you need to map each individual value in the series.

I think the conversion via `datetime` is quite overkill. The substring is already there to grab:

```
df["hours"] = df["Date"].str[11:16]
```

Comment: Or just `df['hours'] = df['Date'].str[11:16]`.

Answer (score 1):

You've passed the whole Series as the parameter to `.strptime`.

This is a minimal, reproducible example that applies a function to each member of the series:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['2021-06-18 23:30:00','2021-06-19 01:02:03'],columns=['Date'])
print(df)
print()
df['hours'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%H:%M'))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  Date
0  2021-06-18 23:30:00
1  2021-06-19 01:02:03

                  Date  hours
0  2021-06-18 23:30:00  23:30
1  2021-06-19 01:02:03  01:02
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` is an add-on to python. To the extent that it's objects expose methods to perform python operations, you can use them with other python modules. But the standard libraries do not have any special code for pandas. In your case you use the standard `datetime` library with a pandas series, but `datetime.strptime` works with a single string. It doesn't know how to apply its functionality to a dataframe.

An alternate is the pandas `apply` method. It will apply regular python code to each item in a pandas dataframe or a series in the dataframe. So you could write a function that does the conversion for each cell in the column

```
import datetime as dt

date_to_hours(datestr):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(datestr,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%H:%M"))

df["Hours"] = df["Date"].apply(date_to_hours)
```

But pandas has a large set of builtin functions that generally work faster than python. Convert that column into a pandas datetime and you can use hours in a manner that is likely faster than the apply method. You'll have different types - hour will now be an integer instead of a string, but will also generally be faster to work with.

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
print(df["Date"].dt.hour)
```

Whether this is the better option depends on what you plan to do with the date later of course.